# wp_create_user not working on plugin file

Tags: plugins

When I use this

```
$create_user = wp_create_user('username', 'password', 'email');
    
    $new_user = new WP_User($create_user);

    $new_user -> set_role('user_role');
```

on my function file of theme. It's working fine.
But When I use this on plugin file. It's showing fetal error.
How should use this ? There is any hook for plugin ?
Thanks

Comment: Plugin or theme shouldn't matter I don't think: plugins are loaded before themes, but I assume this is in an action handler (which action?) and not just at the top level of functions.php? What is the fatal error?

Comment: "There is any hook for plugin" - what sort of hook are you asking for specifically? There's [plugins_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) after all plugins are loaded if that's what you meant.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I found this issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845192/create-new-user-automatically-via-functions-php-in-wordpressI missed the the add_action hook before function.